# Match id in multiple groups in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like below

| Group | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA |
| 1 | BBB |
| 1 | CCC |
| 2 | AAA |
| 2 | DDD |
| 2 | CCC |
| 3 | AAA |
| 3 | GGG |
| 3 | TTT |

Here i want to find the number of ids that are present in "group 1 only", "group 1 and 2", "group 1, 2 and 3".

I want the final table to look like below

| Group | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

This is just an example table but i have 10 groups and millions of rows of data like this and i need an efficient way to calculate the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `crosstab` then `cumsum`

```
pd.crosstab(df.Group,df.ID).cumsum().eq([1,2,3],axis=0).sum(1).reset_index(name='count')
Out[70]: 
   Group  count
0      1      3
1      2      2
2      3      1
```